Kestrel configuration with user certificate
Kestrel is configured for http://[Star].[PortNumber1] and https://[Start].[PortNumber2].
Http is running, but the configuration of https makes problems.
The programm is started from the command line.
Working scenario for https

The process is started with administrative privileges.
The certificate from the LocalMachine store could be referenced via the subject setting in the configuration.
The Service is returning content, no errors or problems in browser on the local machine or on an other device.

If the process is started without the administrative privileges ERR_NO_CONTENT is returned from the service.
I tried the configuration with a certificate from the UserStore (no administrator role)

the certificate is not found by the subject, but the "thumbprint" property of the certificate. As subject i entered the name that is listed in the column "Issued To" in the certmgr application.
the local browser returns content without error if the service is connected via https://localhost:[PortNumber2]
the browser issues a warning if the service is connected via https://[IPAdress] or https://[Hostname] with the warning that the certificate is invalid "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

Do i need a certificate in "LocalMachine" if i want to connect to the service from other devices?
Which permissions does the user without administrative privilieges need to access the certificate from the LocalMachine store?
Why is the personal certificate found only with the "thumbprint" property but not the subject?
